# Why my codeigniter upload didnt run

Tags: php, codeigniter, warnings

I am new here. I already searched around about upload but still didn't work.

this is my controller function

```
    public function tambah() {
        $this->data->error = '';
        if($_POST){   
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->rules);
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/berita/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $config['max_size'] = '2048';
            $config['max_width']  = '650';
            $config['max_height']  = '270';
            $config['encrypt_name']  = 'true';

            $this->load->library('upload',$config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $this->data->error = $this->upload->display_errors();

            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            }
         }
    }
```

and this is my view

```
    <?php 
    if(@$error){echo @$error;}
    echo validation_errors();
    echo form_fieldset('Penambahan Berita','class="berita"');
    echo '<div class="col-left">';
    echo form_open_multipart(site_url(uri_string()));
    echo form_label('Judul');
    echo form_input('judul',@$judul,'class="input-text"');
    echo form_label('Berita');
    echo form_textarea('berita',@$berita,'style="width:300px;height:100px;"');
    echo form_label('Url');
    echo form_input('url',@$url,'class="input-text"');
    echo form_label('Foto');
    echo form_upload('pic');
    echo form_submit('submit','Submit','class="input-submit"');
    echo form_close();
    echo '</div>';  
    echo form_fieldset_close();
    ?>
```

I don't know why, but when I click submit there is warning :

> You did not select a file to upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
  $this->upload->do_upload('pic')
```